# VB.Net -" console.write(Format((87.20 \ 43.60))) " returning result of 1 not 2, why?

Tags: vb.net, report

The below line of code is returning as a 1 instead of a 2, for reasons I can't comprehend.

console.write(Format((87.20 \ 43.60)))

Surely this should return the result of 2 but I've checked in another environment and it returns a can anyone tell me why?

I have tried putting the code into a second environment but the result was the same I don't understand why it is returning 1 instead of 2, can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: Try changing the slash to /

Comment: It's for a report and I need integer division I'm just unsure why it doesn't result in 2.

Comment: Wonder what the real code looks like?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help but found the answer.

Decimals are converted to Long before Integer division and due to this are subject to banker's rounding, multiplying both numbers by a 100 before the operation resolves the issue.

Source of information:

[Learn Microsoft - VB.Net - \ Operator - Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/integer-division-operator#remarks)

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

While I am glad you resolved your own question, I did want to provide an alternative.

When you use the integer division operator, you do not have control as to how the rounding should occur. Whereas if you do a floating-point division operator you can keep the precision and then use one of the built-in Math class methods ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math#methods)) to specify how the number should round.

Take a look at this example:

```vb
Dim result = 87.20 / 43.60
Dim roundUp = Math.Ceiling(result)
Dim roundDown = Math.Floor(result)
Dim bankersRounding = Math.Round(result)
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/LZEMXV

Because in your example you are using `Console.Write` (which treats the data as a String) you do not need to cast the value to an Integer data type. However, if you needed the value as an Integer, any one of those variables outside `result` can be safely converted to an Integer using the Parse method ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.parse)).